# Regex replace and getting: CS1056 Unexpected character '$'

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to convert html code to bbcode and I found this nifty little class packed with regexes that does just that.

```
 public static string ConvertBBCodeToHTML(string str)
    {
        Regex exp;
        // format the bold tags: [b][/b]
        // becomes: <strong></strong>
        exp = new Regex(@"[b](.+?)[/b]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<strong>$1</strong>");

        // format the italic tags: [i][/i]
        // becomes: <em></em>
        exp = new Regex(@"[i](.+?)[/i]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<em>$1</em>");

        // format the underline tags: [u][/u]
        // becomes: <u></u>
        exp = new Regex(@"[u](.+?)[/u]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<u>$1</u>");

        // format the strike tags: [s][/s]
        // becomes: <strike></strike>
        exp = new Regex(@"[s](.+?)[/s]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<strike>$1</strike>");

        // format the url tags: [url=www.website.com]my site[/url]
        // becomes: <a href="www.website.com">my site[/url]
        exp = new Regex(@"[url=([^]]+)]([^]]+)[/url]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<a href="$1">$2[/url]");

        // format the img tags:  
        // becomes: <img src="www.website.com/img/image.jpeg">
        exp = new Regex(@"[img]([^]]+)[/img]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<img src="$1">");

        // format img tags with alt: [img=www.website.com/img/image.jpeg]this is the alt text[/img]
        // becomes: <img src="www.website.com/img/image.jpeg" alt="this is the alt text">
        exp = new Regex(@"[img=([^]]+)]([^]]+)[/img]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<img src="$1" alt="$2">");

        //format the colour tags: [color=red][/color]
        // becomes: <font color="red"></font>
        // supports UK English and US English spelling of colour/color
        exp = new Regex(@"[color=([^]]+)]([^]]+)[/color]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<font color="$1">$2</font>");
        exp = new Regex(@"[colour=([^]]+)]([^]]+)[/colour]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<font color="$1">$2</font>");

        // format the size tags: [size=3][/size]
        // becomes: <font size="+3"></font>
        exp = new Regex(@"[size=([^]]+)]([^]]+)[/size]");
        str = exp.Replace(str, "<font size=" +$1">$2</font>");

        // lastly, replace any new line characters with 

        str = str.Replace("rn", "rn");

        return str;
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting the `CS1056 Unexpected character '$'` error when doing the regex replace even if it seems to be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the embedded double quotes `"` in strings like:

```
"<a href="$1">$2[/url]"
```

They should be:

```
"<a href=\"$1\">$2[/url]"
```

Or with [verbatim string literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
@"<a href=""$1"">$2[/url]"
```

Comment: So right! I could have seen that myself ... Now I get `System.ArgumentException: 'parsing "[url=([^]]+)]([^]]+)[/url]" - Too many )'s.'
` and this time I did tried to escape

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotes to embed values within the string like below:

```
exp = new Regex(@"[url=([^]]+)]([^]]+)[/url]");
str = exp.Replace(str, "<a href='$1'>$2[/url]");
```

Comment: don't forget to mark answered if that fixes your issue.